# hows does Ubuntu software & updates work under the hood

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-drivers

I want to install the latest Nouveau drivers or Nvidia drivers but when i install them manually nothing works (in both cases). When i install them via (Ubuntu Software & Updates) they are installed successfully but do not work as wanted. so i wanted to install the latest drivers (which are not provided by the program) and i wanted to investigate how does (Ubuntu Software & Updates) work so that i mimic/imitate it.

[image: Ubuntu Software & updates]

Comment: There is no question here to be answered. Please add an actual question.

Comment: i meant what are the command that the GUI (Software & updates) executes. for example; if you deselect a repository, it executes `sed` to comment out the repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I am talking about the same thing but in the case of the drivers, idk and what i reached until now is that it is related with something called `ubuntu-drivers`

Comment: My best bet would be to download the corresponding source packages (from Ubuntu) and examine the install scripts.

Comment: that is my point here in the question, what does it do different than what i do so that it works out of the box while the manual method does not work.

Comment: If you want to know what the difference is between what is it that you are doing manually (how are we supposed to know?) to install the nvidia driver and what the debian package is doing, please download the corresponding source package and look at the install scripts.

Comment: that is true, i did not wanted to flood the question with what i do and instead, i will investigate what should be done when someone answers, extremly sorry if i am not clear, i really did my best to do so.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1312777/edit) to be more clear about what exactly you want help with. You are unlikely to get a satisfying answer with your current question.